# Bootstrap 5 container-fluid funciona incorrectamente en mi background-img

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

CODIGO HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PagWeb.css">
  </head>

  
<body id="hoja" data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target=".navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-secondary navbar-dark justify-content-center fixed-top"> <!-- bg: color de barra, navbar: color letra -->                                    
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#Home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Experiencia</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#Educación">Educación</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Hard & Soft Skills">Hard & Soft Skills</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Contáctame">Contánctame</a>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

problema a arreglar

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="fondo1" class="position-relative" id="Home" style="height: 590px; background-image: url(img/fondo.jpg);">
  <img id="foto" class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle rounded-circle" src="img/foto.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

problema a arreglar

```
<div id="Educación" class="pb-3 pt-3" style="background-color: grey;">
<h1 class="text-center text-white mb-3">Educación</h1>
<p class="text-center text-white">Cursando</p>
<p class="text-center text-white">TECNICO SUP EN PROGRAMACIÓN</p>

<div class="clearfix">
  <img src="img/LogoUTN.png" class="col-md-6 img-fluid float-sm-start me-3 ms-md-3"  alt="">
  <p class="text-white">Alcances del título</p> 
  <p class="text-white"> Participar en actividades relacionadas
  a la operación y programación de computadoras en sus distintos niveles. <br> Desarrollar programas de
   computadoras aplicando
   los distintos lenguajes de programación con las diversas metodologías y técnicas. <br>
   Relevar, analizar, implementar, adaptar y controlar con eficiencia y habilidad técnica,
   la programación de los sistemas informáticos. <br>
   Creación, programación y mantenimiento de sistemas y redes de computadoras.
  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Al ejecutarlo en navegador puedo ver que  la imagen de fondo tiene un espacio vacío a su derecha que no se como corregir. además de que tampoco funciona el responsivo de la imagen ni agregando "img fluid" a su "class"

CODIGO CSS

```
#foto {
  width: 190px; height: 190px;
}

#fondo1{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: esta sera la primera ves que le pido al OP que coloque una imagen captura de lo que sale mal en su navegador XD

Comment: Puedes agregar un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví

CODIGO CSS:

```
#fondo1 {
  height: 700px; 
  background: #ccc url("https://placeimg.com/700/400/nature");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

resulta que es mejor no usar el backgraund-image y solo poner una img en mi caso
además el conteiner fluid le estaba agregando bordes indeseables a mi img de fondo
con respecto a la barra grande de la derecha eso pudo haber sido porque me faltaba un background-size: cover;

CODIGO HTML:

```
<div id="fondo1" class="position-relative img-fluid" id="Home" style=" background-image: url(img/fondo.jpg);">
  <img id="foto" class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle rounded-circle" src="img/foto.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: No es que algo sea mejor o no; el problema es cuando se desconoce cómo usarlos correctamente. A tu `id="foto"` le estás agregando un ancho fijo en pixeles, por eso al usar `img-fluid`, que es porcentual y relativo a su contenedor, entra en conflicto. Lo mismo al agregarle position-absolute, esta clase "saca" la imagen de su contenedor, perdiendo así un ancho relativo sobre el cual tomar tamaño.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos cosas mezcladas aquí que puede ser la confusión y el mal funcionamiento: la imagen en modo fondo en un div con CSS, y la imagen en modo etiqueta en el html.

Pero en este caso ambos están en HTML, y no debería ser así, sino, o en CSS o en HTML.

Independientemente Bootstrap, pongo un ejemplo de ambos de cómo debe ser cada uno; para una posible solución.

```css
#fondo1 {
  width: 590px;
  height: 590px; 
  background: #ccc url("https://placeimg.com/700/400/nature");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="fondo1" class="position-relative" id="Home" >
  <img id="foto" class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle rounded-circle" src="img/foto.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

De esta forma la imagen está en el html.

Simplemente el contenedor `#fondo1` es más alto que la imagen (por la imagen sin definir).

```css
#fondo1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 590px;
  height: 590px; 
  background: #ccc
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="fondo1" class="position-relative" id="Home" >
  <img id="foto" class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle rounded-circle" src="https://placeimg.com/700/400/nature" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hola como estas hay coloque el primer código que me mandaste de CSS y HTML pero sigue sin funcionar el responsivo y el tamaño de la imagen sigue sin ser el adecuado. Pero lo bueno es que ahora tengo todo mas ordenado

Comment: según lo que entiendo el problema es el tamaño de la img con respecto al contenedor verdad?

Comment: Si. Puedes hacer lo siguiente: elimina todo estilo de img y deja solamente uno, y a este dale un `width: 100%` y tambien, `margin: 0` `padding: 0` ...